# Specifying random effect nested under an interaction of fixed effects

Tags: nested, lme4, mixed-models, random-effects

Probably an easy one.

I have data with fixed and random effects I'd like to fit a mixed effects model to:

```
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(group = c(rep("A",40),rep("B",40)),
                 treatment = rep(c(rep("T",20),rep("CT",20)),2),
                 class = c(rep("AT1",10),rep("ACT1",10),rep("AT2",10),rep("ACT2",10),rep("BT1",10),rep("BCT1",10),rep("BT2",10),rep("BCT2",10)),
                 value = rnorm(80),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

df$group <- factor(df$group, levels = c("A","B"))
df$treatment <- factor(df$treatment, levels = c("CT","T"))
```

The fixed effects are `group` and `treatment` and the random effect is `class`, which to my understanding is nested within the `group` and `treatment` combinations.

The model I want to fit is:

```
value ~ group*treatment
```

Where the effect of interest if the `group:treatment` interaction.
Of course I want to account for `class` as a random effect, but I can't seem to find what the syntax for that is. I tried:
`(1|group*treatment/class)` and `(1|group:treatment/class)` but both give an error.

Defining a `group:treatment` column in `df`:

```
df <- df %>% dplyr::mutate(group_treatment = paste0(group,"_",treatment))
```

And fitting:

```
fit <- lmer(value ~ group*treatment + (1|group_treatment/class), data = df)
```

Does seem to work, but I'm wondering if that's the only way or whether there's a more explicit syntax for such cases of random effect nesting.

Any idea?

Comment: As far as I know, a fixed effect predictor can't / shouldn't be used at the same time as random _intercept_. However, if you think that the effect of `group` on your outcome varies depending on `class`, than you can specify `group` and/or `treatment` as random _slopes_: `lmer(value ~ group*treatment + (1 + group*treatment | class), data = df)`